# Copy and Paste values

Tags: vba, copy-paste

I have this code, but it copies formulas and I just have values.
I am not too savvy with VBA.

```
Dim sh4 As Worksheet, sh5 As Worksheet, lr As Long, rng As Range

Set sh4 = Sheets("Transfer_New")
Set sh5 = Sheets("Closed_Loans")
lr = sh4.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Set rng = sh4.Range("A2:A" & lr)

Application.Cursor = xlHand

iReply = MsgBox(Prompt:="Are you sure you want to transfer client to CLOSED_LOANS?", _
    Buttons:=vbYesNo, Title:="Document Production")
        If iReply = vbYes Then
            Application.Cursor = xlWait: rng.EntireRow.Copy sh5.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)(2): Application.Cursor = xlNorthwestArrow                    
       End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
   If iReply = vbYes Then
        Application.Cursor = xlWait: rng.EntireRow.Copy sh5.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)(2): Application.Cursor = xlNorthwestArrow                    
   End If
```

To this (there is no really good reason -- certainly not for legibility/clarity -- to put multiple lines of code on one line (that's what the `:` separator does).

```
   If iReply = vbYes Then
        Application.Cursor = xlWait
        rng.EntireRow.Copy sh5.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)(2)
        Application.Cursor = xlNorthwestArrow                    
   End If
```

Then change it to this:

```
   Dim destRng as Range
   Set destRng = sh5.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1,0)
   If iReply = vbYes Then
        Application.Cursor = xlWait
        destRng.Value = rng.Value
        Application.Cursor = xlNorthwestArrow                    
   End If
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to paste values, try this:

```
rng.Entirerow.Copy: sh5.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1,0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

i think thats what's only missing in your code.